# ng test fails on typescript compilation of es6

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, karma-jasmine, angular-cli

When I run ng test on my project I get the following error:

```
ERROR in src/app/components/some.component.ts(177,38): 
error TS2461: Type 'Set<{}>' is not an array type.
```

I presume I have to tell typescript I'm using es6, or the angular-cli... any idea which/how?

I have in my tsconfig.json

```
  "target": "es6",
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ]
```

Using 
    "typescript": "^2.4.2"
    "@angular/cli": "^1.4.9",
and angular 5

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a typescript bug, I had to convert the set to an array then use the spread operator implicitly:

```
[...Array.from(new Set(someArray))];
```